# Show form again if password wrong

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following code which check password/login and do other actions:

```
public virtual void run()
        {
            if (appInitializer!=null)
            {
                ISecurityManager securityManager = appInitializer.SecurityManager;
                if (securityManager!=null)
                {                   
                    if (securityManager.DoLogin())
                    {
                        RegisterDefaultActionsGroup();
                        InitializePlugins(appInitializer.Plugins);
                        ActionsManager.Inst.ApplySecurity(securityManager, securityManager.CurrentUser);
                        mainForm = new MainForm();
                        mainForm.Text = appInitializer.ApplicationTitle;
                        if (appInitializer.ApplicationIcon != null)
                        {
                            mainForm.Icon = appInitializer.ApplicationIcon;
                        }
                        CorrectFormSizes(mainForm);
                        Context[Constants.MainForm] = mainForm;
                        MenuManager.Inst.FillMenu(DefaultGroups.MAIN_MENU, mainForm.MainMenu, ActionClick);
                        if(appInitializer.IsHaveToCreatePanelInfo) PanelInfoManager.Inst.FillInfo(mainForm);
                        if (appInitializer.IsHaveToCreateToolBar)
                        {
                            MenuManager.Inst.FillToolbar(DefaultGroups.MAIN_TOOLBAR, mainForm.MainToolStrip, ActionClick);                            
                        }
                        mainForm.MainToolStrip.Visible = mainForm.MainToolStrip.Items.Count > 0;
                        NotifyPluginsAboutShowing(appInitializer.Plugins);
                        Application.Run(mainForm);
                    }                    
                }
            }
        }
```

The main method is `DoLogin`. If it return true then run other actions(fill menu, create toolbar and other).
The problem is that if user enter wrong password then `DoLogin` returns false and application is closing.
I want that if user enter wrong password then `DoLogin` (inside of method is created form) run again.
How can I rewrite this code to acomplish this?
Thanks.

PS. The `Run` is member of my own Framework class. In the Program.cs file is the following code:

```
static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            Framework framework = new Framework(new EArchiveInitializer());
            framework.run();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just `while (!securityManager.DoLogin()) { }`?